# Escape characters in xml nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a xml like this in string variable ( load from file )

```
<Data>
    <Name>Test & <  test> </Name>
</Data>
```

when i try to load this xml i got exception "an error occured while parsing Node". i think this is due to & in Name tag. I have search on the internet but all solutions (e.g. `SecurityElement.Escape`) escape main xml elements too like greater than to gt and less than to lt and i only want to replace & in my case. i can iterate through xml and replace only data part but is there any shortest way ?

Comment: That's invalid XML. Fix the code that produced this. No serializer is going to accept that `&`. `&` is actually the escape character. All XML serializers, in all languages, will escape `&` correctly

Comment: Yeah, that's not-quite-xml, rather than being actual xml, so it's no surprise that XML tools aren't happy working with it. Like @PanagiotisKanavos, I'd strongly suggest you get this fixed upstream, so that what you're being given is actual XML.

Comment: you are right i wish i can but i am getting this from some other source I have no control over it .

Comment: The escape sequence for `&` is `&amp;`. Escape sequences in HTML and XML start with `&`. You can't replace every `&` in a string with `&amp;` because that would break *valid* escape sequences. You'll have to tell whoever produced this to fix their bug. Or bill them for handling it.

Comment: A possible workaround would be to replace ampersands surrounded by whitespace (eg `text.Replace(" & "," &amp; ")` but obviously that won't handle every case. You'll have to make it explicit to your manager or client that you're handling someone else's *critical* bug (XML is nothing new) and you can't be held responsible if this fails. After all, *none* of the users of that XML will be able to read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngleSharp has an error correcting "XML" parser that works more like an HTML5 or tag soup parser trying to correct and fix such markup errors. For your sample

```
using System;
using AngleSharp.Xml;
using AngleSharp.Xml.Parser;

namespace AngleSharpMalFormedXmlTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var malFormedXml =  @"<Data>
    <Name>Test & <  test> </Name>
</Data>";

            var doc = new XmlParser(new XmlParserOptions() { IsSuppressingErrors = true }).ParseDocument(malFormedXml);

            Console.WriteLine(doc.ToMarkup());
        }
    }
}
```

I get

```
<Data>
    <Name>Test &amp;&lt;  test&gt; </Name>
</Data>
```

But once you open up your input to such kind of mal-formed XML you can easily run into misconceptions and incompatibilities or tool-dependency which using a W3C standard like XML was meant to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no control over the source, you could try some regex to make it a valid xml:

```cs
string xml = @"<Data>
    <Name>Test & test&amp; &1 &lt;aaa &</Name>
</Data>";

xml = Regex.Replace(xml,@"&(?!\w+;)","&amp;");
```

this will return

```xml
<Data>
    <Name>Test &amp; test&amp; &amp;1 &lt;aaa &amp;</Name>
</Data>
```

Comment: What happens with `&</Name>` ?

Comment: what if name tag contains < tag too ( updating my question )

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal then you stop trying to fix someone else's *completely* broken string. That's not XML any more. You can't keep guessing what is broken

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it will produce `&amp;</Name>` i updated the example

Answer (score 0):

The presented XML is not well-formed.

You can use *CData section* to make your XML well-formed.

- Each `<Name>` should become `<Name><![CDATA[`
- Each `</Name>` should become `]]></Name>`

**well-formed XML**

```
<Data>
    <Name><![CDATA[Test & <  test> ]]></Name>
</Data>
```